# Tips to make trains more profitable

Tags: transport-fever-2

I struggle to making my trains profitable, to a stupid degree.

On my train lines I always seem to run a deficit of almost a million a month, that I have to catch up with my bus/plane routes.

But that becomes problematic in chapter 13, where its Japan and you don't have much truck routes and the trains they request me having are running a 2-3 million a month.

It really makes me feel that I've missed some basics.

So what are some major points to check to help train routes profitable?

Answer (score 2):

In Transport Fever games in general, there is a point-to-point trip model of traffic: A person that is taking "lines" from one point to another somewhere on the map will try to figure out a route using any combination of lines that are connected by having stations that are in each others' footprints, even different modes of transportation (train, bus, ferry, plane).

To build the number of trips through your network you need to build up the footprint of buildings that your network covers. Obviously you can't practically put down individual train stations so that the footprint of just the stations covers much of a city; so to build intercity passenger rail volume, you also need good local tram or bus connections from your train stations that cover the area of the city.

For higher difficultly, and map situations where money is tight, you always want to balance having the absolute most city bus/tram coverage with saving money on vehicle spending; a focus on building routes that are good value in terms of how many passengers will use them -- the traffic they will add to your overall network; you don't need another tram stop that mostly covers area already served by an existing tram stop or in mostly empty area that only adds a couple of buildings, and you don't need that second or third tram line just to add one more station that is going to run nearly empty and just lose money and make your cash flow problem even worse.

Aside from that you want to keep an eye on the upfront cost and running cost of vehicle choices you use for those lines so that you're keeping costs low as well as revenues high.

One thing I should add about the campaign missions: there are always options.  For whatever aspect isn't nailed down by a specific mission requirement, how you complete it is your choice. In general you only need to satisfy the objectives at one point in time and once that's done you can sell/dismantle stuff you built for it that you don't need anymore unless it's also a requirement for some later goal.

Answer (score 1):

**Goods supply & demand:**

- Everything in the game is based on demand. If for example the goods chain is logging camp -> sawmill -> tool factory -> city, then the maximum amount of tools that will be produced are about as many as the town requires. The tool factory will not make more tools than what is required by the town(s) you deliver to. And therefore will not request more boards from the sawmill than to cover that tool amount. And so on. So when demands increase, the whole chain becomes more profitable.
- The above also means that you cannot realistically make longterm profit on something like solely delivering coal to a steel mill. Because there is no demand in the other end of it. They will order as much coal as they need to fill up their stock, then stop requesting it.

  So complex production chains (like those involving steel for example) are much more expensive to build, because you have to take them all the way to whatever end product that is made from it all. Starting with simpler ones like stone -> construction materials -> city is much easier.
- When an industry is running at high production over a long period of time, it will level up and increase its capacity further.

  Regarding the campaign or early start trains from 1850, they are simply not very profitable. Because they move so slowly, have tiny wagons and can't pull much goods, so they struggle to keep up a pace where industries will get levelled up. It's fairly easy to make the mistake of investing in lots of train infrastructure and then these early age trains are too crappy to return the investment any time soon. Expand carefully until you get the hang of it.
- Make sure that whatever delivers the tools to the city has as many buildings with tool demands covered as possible. You can check this in the various overlays and by clicking on the station where you deliver the goods to. A train station built a bit carelessly might not cover much of the city and then you need to build a little truck chain moving the goods from the train station to where they need to go in the city.
- Don't hesitate to optimize the city's road network at your own expense if this means better goods coverage. For example a train station in the middle of the city will have much better coverage if connected to roads from 2 or 3 sides rather than just 1.
- As you deliver demanded goods, the city will grow, and as it grows, the demands will too.
- Passengers aren't usually very profitable and the main reason you haul them around is actually that doing so makes towns grow. Also, the more passengers you move, the less car traffic there will be, which is important since car traffic will easily clog up your truck/bus logistic routes. The local bus line within a city is rarely ever profitable in itself, but it may take passengers to more profitable ways of transport like the train station or airport.

  You can safely ignore passengers early on and instead focus on a town's goods demands.

**Silly game mechanics:**

- Whatever you ship, you are paid in relation to have far a distance (as the bird flies) you haul it. This isn't very realistic, but the key to making major cash is to haul things ridiculous distances. Also this is why planes are so easy to make profitable. The key to big profits is to move things far away fast.

  For example, if you have a logging camp at the end of the map, next to a tool factory, it is *way* more profitable to haul logs all across the map to a sawmill in the middle of nowhere, then haul boards all the way back, than to just use a nearby sawmill instead.
- One "power gaming" setup is therefore to build 2 massive train stations at each end of the map, make sure to haul needed goods to those, then have trains running back and forth.

**Train logistics:**

- Always build 2 tracks in every direction. Having a single train alone on a track is not very profitable nor scalable. With 2 tracks, one in each direction, you can run as many trains as there are rail segments between signals.
- This means that all your stations need a setup with at least 2 terminals. Make it so that the entering track can reach both terminals and both terminals can reach the exiting track. The simplest and most common setup is to use 2 straight tracks then "draw an X" with new track across them (this would be where Youtube is better for explaining).
- Make sure that all stations have enough room to store goods. If you deliver more goods than there is room, it will quickly "decay" and you fail to deliver it. Better to design capacity with margins.
- Keep in mind that similar goods can be shipped together using the same kind of wagons. If you for example use open wagons for hauling wood, you can also use the same wagons for hauling steel.